# My .remove() isn't removing all the numbers from the list even though I'm passing it through an iterator. I can't seem to find the issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def thirdMax(nums):

    highest = max(nums)

    for i in nums:
        if i == highest:
            nums.remove(i)
    print(nums)

    secondHighest = max(nums)

    for i in nums:
        if i == secondHighest:
            nums.remove(i)

    thirdHighest = max(nums)

    return thirdHighest

thirdMax([1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4])
```

My code is supposed to return the third highest distinct number. My code isn't seeming to work accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the list (to make sure). Convert to a set. Convert back to a list and take the 3rd from the right.

```
l = [1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]
l.sort()
s = set(l)
l = list(s)
third = l[-3]
```

You can combine some of these steps, but I wrote them all out for clarity :)

Comment: Oh that's a much easier way to go about it. But why wasn't my iteration removal method working?

Comment: Because remove only removed the first instance of the value it finds. In your case the 2 removed will reach remove a 4, leaving 4 as the highest number still.